# Extract Key pair Using Lodash Library

Tags: json, lodash

I have JSON Object

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "customer":101,
         "profile":7,
         "context":{  
            "rows":20,
            "from":"2016-01-05T06:14:02.750Z",
            "filter_group_id":null,
            "order":"desc",
            "q":"host",
            "start":0,
            "source_group_id":null,
            "hi":"",
            "filters":[  

            ],
            "terms":"host",
            "source_group_name":null,
            "until":"2016-01-05T07:14:02.750Z"
         },
         "search_type":"searchui",
         "search_time":"2016-01-05 13:33:01",
         "id":724
      },
      {  
         "customer":101,
         "profile":7,
         "context":{  
            "rows":20,
            "from":"2016-01-05T06:14:02.750Z",
            "filter_group_id":null,
            "order":"desc",
            "q":"host",
            "start":0,
            "source_group_id":null,
            "hi":"",
            "filters":[  

            ],
            "terms":"host",
            "source_group_name":null,
            "until":"2016-01-05T07:14:02.750Z"
         },
         "search_type":"searchui",
         "search_time":"2016-01-05 13:26:42",
         "id":723
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to extract key value pair from above json data like below using lodash.

I'm novice lodash libray user. I read about _.map, _.any but unable to implement as per requirement.

Expected JSON Object:

```
[
    {
        "id":724
        "search_time":"2016-01-05 13:33:01",
        "filters":[],
        "from":"2016-01-05T06:14:02.750Z",
        "until":"2016-01-05T07:14:02.750Z"
        "terms":"host",
        "source_group_name":null,
    },
    {
        "id":723
        "search_time":"2016-01-05 13:26:42",
        "filters":[],
        "from":"2016-01-05T06:14:02.750Z",
        "until":"2016-01-05T07:14:02.750Z",
        "terms":"host",
        "source_group_name":null,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
var newArray = [];
_.each(data, function(item){
    newArray.push({
       "id":item.id
        "search_time":item.search_time,
        "filters":context.filters,
        ...etc...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the more performatic way, but I think it works.

```
 var dataFilter = _.map(data, function(value){
    return _.merge(
          _.pick(value.context, 'filters', 'from', 'until', 'terms', 'source_group_name'),
          _.pick(value, 'id', 'search_time')
    );
 });
```